# Triangle inequality for negative?

Tags: inequality

Does the following hold? If so, why?

$||x - y| - |x - z|| \leq |y - z|$

Comment: yes, triangle ${}$

Comment: First off, you don't need double bars. Second, note that rearranging the terms gives you the triangle inequality.

Comment: [Reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)

Comment: Reversed version! thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x-y| \leq |x-z|+|y-z| \Longrightarrow |x-y| -|x-z| \leq |y-z|$

$|x-z| \leq |x-y|+|y-z| \Longrightarrow |x-y| -|x-z| \geq -|y-z|$

So combining the above,the inequality holds